# Pass Minus Values for a SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, ssms

I need to pass a value for a SP by multiply it by -1.

This is my query and I want pass the quantity by multiply it by -1.

```
SELECT top 1 @partid=partid, @unitCostU=unit_cost, @Quantity=qty
FROM parts_table

Exec ins_exusage @partid, 4, @Quantity, @unitCost
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: It doesn't matter what a parameter's value contains.  Is your real question the *reverse* of what you posted? How to *retrieve* the negative of a value? Just put `-` in front

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your fist query to negate the sign `@Quantity = -qty`

```
SELECT top 1 
       @partid = partid ,
       @unitCostU = unit_cost, 
       @Quantity = -qty 
FROM  @partstable
```

OR multiply it by `-1`

```
@Quantity = qty * -1
```